# Styling issues with Highcharts JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to make a line graph and have it pretty close to the design I need. I can't seem to get the xAxis to start and end at the edge. I don't want any space between the yAxis and the first plot line. Just using the:

```
xAxis: {
    startOnTick: true,
    endOnTick: true
}
```

doesn't seem to do what I need. Am I missing something?

I also need the yAxis to not start at the bottom or end at the top. I want the first tick to be on the second spot and the names, "Revenue" and "Order Volume", to be at the top with the last tick one line below. I also can't seem to get them align in the same way that all the labels are.
Here is what I have it looking like now http://jsfiddle.net/kyu3eh6L/

This is what the end result needs to look like. http://postimg.org/image/y3otwee3d/

Any help would be much appreciate. I can't seem to find what I need in their API.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit much between your current state and end result, but I'll address two of your stated concerns. First:

> I can't seem to get the xAxis to start and end at the edge

This is a bit of a weird one, but here's my suggested solution, which works specifically for x-axis with categories:

```
var categories = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'];

$('#container').highcharts({
    // ...
    xAxis: {
        categories: categories,
        min: 0.5,
        max: categories.length - 1.5,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false
        // ...
    }
});
```

You also stated that:

> I want the first tick to be on the second spot and the names, "Revenue" and "Order Volume", to be at the top with the last tick one line below.

One way of doing both with the same operation is utilizing a `formatter` for the labels. For example:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    // ...
    yAxis: [{
        // ...
        title: {
            text: 'Revenue ($)',
            enabled: false
        },
        labels: {
            // ...
            formatter: function() {
                if(this.isLast) {
                    return this.axis.options.title.text;
                }
                else if(!this.isFirst) {
                    return this.value+"k";
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    },
    //...
    ]
});
```

See [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyu3eh6L/3/) for how these changes may look.

Answer (score 1):

To start and end at the edge just set `pointPlacement: 'on'` on `plotOptions.series`. To place the title, use the x and y options. Try http://jsfiddle.net/kyu3eh6L/4/